# Google Anchor ads at the top of the page hiding website header

Tags: css, anchor, adsense

Google Anchor ads are Mobile ads that stick to the edge of the user’s screen. My issue is, this ad is hiding the header of the website. I know I have an option of sticking it at the bottom but I don't want to do it that way. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Without a link it is hard to know for sure but I assume that the advertisement is fixed. Adding a `margin-top` to the HTML element equal to the height of the advertisement might fix this.

Example: https://codepen.io/trvswgnr/pen/jepWPN